# Lorentz time transformation in terms of $x$ and $x'$

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I was going through a worked special relativity example and found the following transformation equation, which I have not come across before. I tried but cannot derive it. Can anybody help?

$$ct'=\frac{1}{\beta  (-x'+\frac{x}{\gamma})}$$

I think it comes from substituting $t$ from the $x$ to $x'$ transformation but I cannot see how.

Comment: What's $\beta$?

Comment: @YoungKindaichi I've learned that $\beta = \frac{v}{c}$ where $v$ is the speed of which some observer/inertial frame of reference is moving away from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward algebra. Starting with the standard formula for the reverse Lorentz Transform $(x'\rightarrow 
x)$:
$$
x = \gamma(x' + vt')\\
\frac{x}{\gamma} = x' + vt'\\
vt' = -x' + \frac{x}{\gamma}\\
\beta ct' = -x' + \frac{x}{\gamma}, \ \text{as} \ \beta = \frac{v}c\\
ct' = \frac{1}\beta (-x' + \frac{x}{\gamma})
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel a bit silly now after seeing how straight-forward it is!

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Newbie here.